# Kafka - Unable to send a message to a remote server using Java

Tags: java, linux, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a `Kafka` cluster to send messages to a remote control. I have configured everything as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example).
I am running this on a `Linux red hat` machine, and it works fine using the shell. After writing the java code as described in the `quick start` tutorial on my windows machine, I have received the following error:

```
...
DEBUG kafka.client.ClientUtils$ - Successfully fetched metadata for 1 topic(s)     Set(example)
...
ERROR kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Producer connection to cldExampleKafka.domain:80 unsuccessful 
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    ...
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:44)
...
WARN kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler - Failed to send producer request with correlation id 2 to broker 0 with data for patitions [ati,0]
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
...
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send message after 3 tries.
```

I have also tried to run the jar in a different Linux machine, and still received the same error.

Changing the address to `localhost` and running the java code as a jar in the machine where the kafka is installed works.

I believe it something with the configuration, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your kafka `server.properties` there is a commented configuration

```
#advertised.host.name=<Some IP>
```

Uncomment this and add the IP of the Linux Machine in which kafka is running.

```
advertised.host.name=<Kafka Running Machine IP>
```

And connect from clients to `<Kafka Running Machine IP>` This should fix your issue.

**EDIT**

Optionally you can uncomment the

```
#advertised.port=9092
```

Also if you are listening on a different port than the default one.

Comment: Does it also needs to change zookeeper configuration??because i  still having problem

Comment: I had to mention both host.name  and advertised.host.name to make it work.

Comment: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ explains this in more detail

Comment: I didn't find this entry in server.properties, but the answer from Dhananjay works for me.

Answer (score 21):

Worked with

from `server.properties` Uncomment

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

And

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<HOST IP>:9092
```

Replace `<HOST IP>` with actual IP.

Comment: can you please share your actual config

Comment: Tried connecting to kafka remote cluster from VM.
VM's had 1 internal(9.0.0.1 and external ip(192.1.1.1) i could ssh only to the internal & not the external, changes to my conifg/server.properties                                                                                                                                                                                           //give the ip in the machine when u do ifconfig or hostname -I
'code' listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.1.1.1:9092
//give the ip consumer and producer will connect
'code' advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://9.0.0.1:9092

Answer (score 4):

in 
`config/server.properties` 
I put this 
`listeners=PLAINTEXT://[server_ip]:9092`

and it worked fine.

For quick testing, don't forget to use [server_ip] in the command line of kafka-consumer.
Example:

```
/usr/local/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/kafka-console-consumer.sh --property print.timestamp=true --bootstrap-server [server_ip]:9092 --topic [you_topic]
```

I hope this may help you.
Regards
Ali

Answer (score 1):

Tried connecting to kafka remote cluster from my local machine.

VM's had one internal (9.0.0.1) and one external IP (192.1.1.1). I could ssh only to the internal & not the external. I did these changes to my conifg/server.properties:

//set to the IP of the machine (find using `ifconfig` or `hostname -I`)

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.1.1.1:9092
```

//set to the IP the consumer and producer will connect

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://9.0.0.1:9092
```