# Fail to export from voltdb to kafka

Tags: export, voltdb, apache-kafka

VoltDB is enterprise 5.1.2
Kafka is 2.9.2-0.8.1.1, also tried 2.10-0.8.2.1

VoltDB is at 192.168.56.101
Kafka is at 192.168.56.102

Here is my deployment configuration for VoltDB:

```
<deployment>
  <cluster hostcount="1" sitesperhost="4" kfactor="0" />

  <commandlog enabled="true">
    <frequency time="400" transactions="1000"  />
  </commandlog>

  <export>
    <configuration enabled="true" type="kafka" stream="archive">
      <property name="metadata.broker.list">192.168.56.102:9092</property>
      <property name="producer.type">sync</property>
      <property name="batch.mode">true</property>
    </configuration>
  </export>
</deployment>
```

The schema is defined as:

```
drop table person if exists;
create table person (
  ic varchar(9) not null,
  first_name varchar(20) not null,
  last_name varchar(20) not null,
  middle_name varchar(20),
  gender tinyint not null,
  dob timestamp not null,
  date_created timestamp default now
);
partition table person on column ic;

export table person to stream archive;
```

And for server.properties of Kafka, I only added this line

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

I first started Kafka as following:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-startsh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

When I start VoltDB, I encounter this exception:

```
david@u14voltdb:~$ voltdb create catalog.jar --deployment=config.xml
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0
Initializing VoltDB...

 _    __      ____  ____  ____ 
| |  / /___  / / /_/ __ \/ __ )
| | / / __ \/ / __/ / / / __  |
| |/ / /_/ / / /_/ /_/ / /_/ / 
|___/\____/_/\__/_____/_____/

--------------------------------

Build: 5.1.2 voltdb-5.1.2-0-g6d05c33-local Enterprise Edition
Connecting to VoltDB cluster as the leader...
Host id of this node is: 0
Starting VoltDB with trial license. License expires on May 31, 2015.
Initializing the database and command logs. This may take a moment...
WARN: Failed to send producer request with correlation id 2 to broker 0     with data for partitions [voltdbexportPERSON,0]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:97)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:71)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:255)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:106)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:631)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:161)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:80)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:76)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:42)
    at org.voltdb.exportclient.KafkaExportClient$KafkaExportDecoder.onBlockCompletion(KafkaExportClient.java:217)
    at org.voltdb.export.processors.GuestProcessor$2.run(GuestProcessor.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.voltcore.utils.CoreUtils$7$1.run(CoreUtils.java:735)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

At the Kafka side, I keep getting this:

```
[2015-05-14 00:40:08,197] INFO Closing socket connection to /192.168.56.101. (kafka.network.Processor)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem solved. Its nothing to do with VoltDB. The solution is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146409/kafka-unable-to-send-a-message-to-a-remote-server-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely an issue related to Kafka setting. In the setting, there is a commented setting:

```
advertised.host.name=something
```

just need to replace "something" to the IP address of the server in which Kafka is running. This is found at [Kafka - Unable to send a message to a remote server using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146409/kafka-unable-to-send-a-message-to-a-remote-server-using-java)