# kafka producer in A server however consumer in B server

Tags: apache-kafka

I run Kafka server on A computer successfully.

However, I run Kafka consumer on B computer, the command and result as follows:

command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.78.131:9092 --topic test
```

192.168.78.131 is A server

results:

```
[2018-04-17 22:31:55,373] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-47514] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)[2018-04-17 22:31:55,430] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-47514] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)[2018-04-17 22:31:55,549] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-47514] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)[2018-04-17 22:31:55,755] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-47514] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)[2018-04-17 22:31:56,221] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-47514] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

by the way, in A server the own consumer use localhost or 127.0.0.1 to connect Kafka server works but use IP doesn't work too.
What's wrong with these? 
thanks sincerely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146409/kafka-unable-to-send-a-message-to-a-remote-server-using-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: thank you every one